# Flutter App Name Appear as "CURLlogger" Although it used to appear correctly before

Tags: android, flutter

I have a problem that my app name doesn't appear correctly when installed on my phone (when I am using it as an emulator). instead, it appears as "CURLlogger" as shown in the image [app name as appearing on phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4zbf.png).

I have searched for such a problem but couldn't find anything useful. It is important to note that it suddenly changed as previously the app used to appear with its name correctly. I don't know if this is something related to the emulation process and will go away once the app is installed via google play.

This is my first app and is still in development but will be released in the upcoming days.

Comment: Can you post content of <your project path>/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

Please verify the application name string is correct at the following positions:

- in your **pubspec.yml** make sure you have defined the correct name value

```yaml
name: your app name
```

- inside your Android module double-check for the `label` string in **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
     android:label="your app name"
     android:name="${applicationName}"
     android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
     .....
</application>
```

- for iOS, double check the `CFBundleName` key in **info.plist** file:

```xml
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>your app name</string>
```